# Multiple cURL request in a loop

Tags: php, curl

I have a code top fetch the Call List from an API. I receive the data and place it in a table. The  received data includes : **Call From, Call To, Date and Call ID.**

Now I place the data in the Table and an additional field is added to Play the recording of the call. Now I have to make another request to second API along with the CALL ID that was received in the previous Request.
 The flow diagram is :
[image]

My code looks like this :

```
    $post_url = "https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/MANDE1OGM2ZGQ5ZDIWOD/Call/?from_number=".$numberOfCaller;

     $AuthID = "MANDE1OGM2ZZXXXXXXXX" ;
     $AuthToken = "MjE2ZmRjY2FjZWE4ZWE4ZWM0NmNkXXXXXXXX";
    $curl = curl_init($post_url);

    $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$AuthID:$AuthToken");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    $post_response = curl_exec($curl); 

    $post_response=json_decode($post_response);

?>

<tr>
<td><div class="grid_heading">Call From</div></td>
<td><div class="grid_heading">Call To</div></td>
<td><div class="grid_heading">Call Date/Time</div></td>
<td><div class="grid_heading">Play</div></td>

<?php foreach($post_response->objects as $call){
                        //echo "<pre>";
                        //print_r($call); ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><div class="grid_content editable"> <?php echo $call->from_number; ?>      </div></td>
                            <td><div class="grid_content editable"> <?php echo $call->to_number; ?>        </div></td>
                            <td><div class="grid_content editable"> <?php echo $call->call_duration; ?>    </div></td>
                            <td><div class="grid_content editable"> <?php echo $call->total_amount; ?>     </div></td>

<!-- My Second cURL request goes here that will fetch Call ID from previous Request's result and make a new request based on the same -->

<?php

   $audioLink = $plivocalls->call_uuid;         // The CALL ID that was fetched


 $ch = curl_init('https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/'.$auth_id.'/Recording/?call_uuid='.$call->call_uuid); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$auth_id:$auth_token");
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 //echo ($result);
 curl_close($ch);

//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($result);
foreach($result->objects as $plivocalls){

// I need only one output that is 'recording URL'

   $recordLink = $plivocalls->recording_url;
   //echo $recordLink;

 ?> 

<td>
 <img id="playonclick" rel="<?php echo $recordLink; ?>"  src="../images/play_icon.png" alt="Play Call" title="Play Call" />
</td>

<?php } ?>             <!-- Closing ForEach for second request -->

</tr>

<?php } ?>             <!-- Closing ForEach for initial request -->
```

Now I am getting the first and second request perfectly executed. But my query is that when I make FIRST request, I receive a few results. I have to fetch one result value and send SECOND request and get the result that is to be looped in the last .

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: The problem is that I am fetching all the call 'recording_url' at once but not as $recordlink from each record individually.I want it to display in my table in front of each record, it should display appropriate recording Url.